# Animator in c++/cli winforms?

Tags: .net, winforms, dll, c++-cli

I found this article in codeproject

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/548769/Animator-for-WinForms

I wanted to use animator for 2nd form (myform1.h) opening 
I added animator.dll to reference under solution. there are no compilation error but i see runtime error

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.TypeLoadException' occurred in
>   Animator.exe
>
> Additional information: Could not load type 'AnimatorNS.Animation'
>   from assembly 'Animator, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

Here's my code

```
#pragma once
#include"MyForm1.h"

namespace Animator {

    using namespace System;
    using namespace System::ComponentModel;
    using namespace System::Collections;
    using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
    using namespace System::Data;
    using namespace System::Drawing;

    /// <summary>
    /// Summary for MyForm
    /// </summary>
    public ref class MyForm : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
    {
    public:
        MyForm(void)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //
            //TODO: Add the constructor code here
            //
        }

    protected:
        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        ~MyForm()
        {
            if (components)
            {
                delete components;
            }
        }
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button1;
    private: AnimatorNS::Animator^  animator1;

    private: System::ComponentModel::IContainer^  components;
    protected:

    private:
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>


#pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        void InitializeComponent(void)
        {
            this->components = (gcnew System::ComponentModel::Container());
            AnimatorNS::Animation^  animation1 = (gcnew AnimatorNS::Animation());
            System::ComponentModel::ComponentResourceManager^  resources = (gcnew System::ComponentModel::ComponentResourceManager(MyForm::typeid));
            this->button1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
            this->animator1 = (gcnew AnimatorNS::Animator(this->components));
            this->SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // button1
            // 
            this->animator1->SetDecoration(this->button1, AnimatorNS::DecorationType::None);
            this->button1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(56, 93);
            this->button1->Name = L"button1";
            this->button1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(133, 23);
            this->button1->TabIndex = 0;
            this->button1->Text = L"Show form";
            this->button1->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this->button1->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &MyForm::button1_Click);
            // 
            // animator1
            // 
            this->animator1->AnimationType = AnimatorNS::AnimationType::Scale;
            this->animator1->Cursor = nullptr;
            animation1->AnimateOnlyDifferences = true;
            animation1->BlindCoeff = (cli::safe_cast<System::Drawing::PointF>(resources->GetObject(L"animation1.BlindCoeff")));
            animation1->LeafCoeff = 0;
            animation1->MaxTime = 1;
            animation1->MinTime = 0;
            animation1->MosaicCoeff = (cli::safe_cast<System::Drawing::PointF>(resources->GetObject(L"animation1.MosaicCoeff")));
            animation1->MosaicShift = (cli::safe_cast<System::Drawing::PointF>(resources->GetObject(L"animation1.MosaicShift")));
            animation1->MosaicSize = 0;
            animation1->Padding = System::Windows::Forms::Padding(0);
            animation1->RotateCoeff = 0;
            animation1->RotateLimit = 0;
            animation1->ScaleCoeff = (cli::safe_cast<System::Drawing::PointF>(resources->GetObject(L"animation1.ScaleCoeff")));
            animation1->SlideCoeff = (cli::safe_cast<System::Drawing::PointF>(resources->GetObject(L"animation1.SlideCoeff")));
            animation1->TimeCoeff = 0;
            animation1->TransparencyCoeff = 0;
            this->animator1->DefaultAnimation = animation1;
            // 
            // MyForm
            // 
            this->AutoScaleDimensions = System::Drawing::SizeF(8, 16);
            this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
            this->ClientSize = System::Drawing::Size(282, 255);
            this->Controls->Add(this->button1);
            this->animator1->SetDecoration(this, AnimatorNS::DecorationType::None);
            this->Name = L"MyForm";
            this->Text = L"MyForm";
            this->ResumeLayout(false);

        }
#pragma endregion
    private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
        AnimatorNS::AnimationType ^ani = AnimatorNS::AnimationType::Scale;
        MyForm1 ^mf;
        animator1->Show(mf, false, AnimatorNS::Animation::Scale);
        //mf.ShowDialog();


    }
    };
}
```

Comment: Codeproject.com code forever lacks the "Works only on my machine" disclaimer.  You'll have to debug it, looking at the InnerException is the first crucial step.